# Laravel save an array of data in individual rows

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, arraylist, laravel-7

How can I save an array of data into individual rows in Laravel ?

Here's how my UI looks like
[image]

once i click the save button in the controller Store function gets the data

```
public function store(Request $request, $venue, CustomProduct $customProduct)
{
 dd($request->Availability);
}
```

This is how the data looks like

[image]

I'm wondering how can i save this to my database ?

This is how my database table looks like

[image]

Please suggest me a way that i can save this to my table

Comment: You might want to look up "how to loop over associative arrays in php".

Comment: day_id comes from monday, tuesday, ..,? If yes in you html you should replace names to ID's.

Comment: Your example data only has starts_at and ends_at equivalent values. from where you would get `day_id` and `custom_products_id` ?

Comment: @hmrneves Yes, okay ill rename it to id,

Comment: @mosharaf when adding a custom_product i have the Availability input, Availabilities saves into a different table with the custom_products_id

Answer (score 0):

Use this example:

```
$days = ["monday","thursday","wednesday","tuesday","friday","saturday","sunday"];

forach($request->Availability as $key => $value){
     CustomProductAvalibility::create([
         'day_id'    => array_search($key), // array_search($key) returns day id
         'starts_at' => $value["start"],
         'ends_at'   => $value["end"],
         'custom_product_id' => '...' // your custom product id
     ]);
}
```